# How do I remap pan hotkey in UV image editor?

Tags: shortcut

I've made a number of changes to the hotkeys, and I have managed to remove the hotkey for 'pan' in the UV image editor (currently the MMB will set my 2D cursor position). Does anyone know where the key mapping is located for pan in 2D mode or UV image editor mode? I can't find it anywhere and would rather not do a "factory reset" on all the hotkeys due to the number of changes I have made.

This is what I see when I filter on 'pan' for user input:

[image: Filtered shortcut list]

Comment: Answer is here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73253/cannot-remap-pan-hotkey-in-uv-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python for that is `view2d.pan`.
[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately no luck. RMB seems to activate a small information toolbar at the bottom of the UV Image Editor.