# Cannot remap pan hotkey in UV editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

For the life of me I cannot figure this out. I am trying to get the view in the UV editor to pan when the MMB is clicked, like it normally does. But nothing I do works. I already made a post about this :

[How do I remap pan hotkey in UV image editor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51331/how-do-i-remap-pan-hotkey-in-uv-image-editor)

But still I cannot find the right shortcut key. Here are my current settings:

[image]

I have been trying for so long to get this to work. If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably adding it in the wrong window context

For the *UV Image Editor* the  operator is `image.view_pan` and is supposed to be added in the *Image* category

There also seems to be an entry for `view2d.pan` in both the *View 2D* and *View2D Buttons List* category

All set to *Mouse Middle Press* events

Comment: Man, you're a real savior. Thank you so much!